# TS rxjs-compat doesn't support prototype operators?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-compat

I'm following [this migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md) to update from *rxjs 5.5.5 to 6.*.**. 
It looks from this article and many other posts that simply having *rxjs-compat* in my project will allow to migrate step-by-step. Even worse it seems to work for everyone else. What I understand is that *rxjs-compat* will allow me to use both pipeable operators as well as Observable prototype operators. But either this is not the case with *rxjs-compat* or something is wrong.

So my expectation is for instance that I can use *map* in both forms when observable is imported from `rxjs`. But I get the following error *"error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'."*. Which of course means that typings are incorrect.

```
import {of} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

const arr$ = of([1, 2, 3, 4]);
arr$.map(x=> console.log(x));
arr$.pipe(
    map(x => console.log(x))
);
```

I've tried different versions of typescript (`2.7.2`,`2.9.1`,`3.1.1`) also *rxjs* and *rxjs-compat* starting from `6.0.0` till the `latest` vesrion. Also tried playing with *tsconfig paths* and aliasing *rxjs to rxjs-compat* but its never enough.

So just tell me the truth, does it really support prototype operators. Do I need some additional config? some matching versions? anything?

I can provide additional info if needed (package.json, tsconfig, etc).

[this is setup](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pnaidg) that can be downloaded for testing. Locally I just run *tsc index* and it fails

Comment: In your linked StackBlitz, the import from `'rxjs/Rx'` isn't right. The latter should be a default import, which pulls in the all RxJS 5 functionality (i.e. `import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'`). If you wanted to import the RxJS 5 `Observable` only, it should be: `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'`. Furthermore, if you wanted the RxJS 5 `map` only, it should be: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'` (i.e. a side-effect import which presumably monkey-patches the prototype).

Comment: @miqh, sorry for that, I was playing with StackBlitz and messed it. you're right, I have to do ` import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'`. But when I do it rxjs5 way and try to use Observable.of, for instance, there is no `of` on `Observable`.  Same with prototype operators. So I have implicitly to do `import from 'rxjs-compat'` or as you suggested `import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'` to patch these functionality. And that's what  I've expected from rxjs-compat.

Comment: That's okay, I just thought I'd point those things out in case you missed it. So after the import corrections, are you still getting the TS compiler complaining at you? If you want to use the prototype-based RxJS operators, it's inevitable that you need to perform an import, because the action of doing so adds to the prototype of instances.